# How to change android chrome browser orientation using appium with Java

Tags: java, webdriver, appium

Im getting below exception while using below code

```
DesiredCapabilities  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");      
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); 

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ROTATABLE, true);    

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");

driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get("http://gmail.com");    
((Rotatable) driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:

```
unimplemented command: session/499d07270cddecd7890c7a909641ecf1/orientation
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
System info: host: 'BALAP-HYD', ip: '10.144.22.34', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=44.0.2403.133, platform=ANDROID, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

`Session ID: 499d07270cddecd7890c7a909641ecf1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this before rotation:

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```